# SQL Newbie Needs Assistance w/ Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Below is what I am trying to do in SQL Server 2012.  I want to Update Table 2 with the % of total that each AMT value is to the total in Table 1.  But the denominator to get the % should only be the total of the rows that have the same MasterDept.  I can use this SELECT query to get the correct percentages when I load the table with only one MasterDept but do not know how to do it when there are multiple MasterDept.  The first 2 columns in each table are identical both in structure and the data within the columns.

```
SELECT ABCID,
     [AMT%] = ClientSpreadData.AMT/CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,4),(SELECT SUM(ClientSpreadData.AMT) 
     FROM ClientSpreadData))
FROM ClientSpreadData
```

Table data

```
TABLE 1 (MasterDept varchar(4), ABCID varchar(20), AMT INT)
Sample Data (4700, 1, 25),
            (4300, 2, 30),
            (4700, 3, 50),
            (4300, 4, 15)

TABLE 2 (MasterDept varchar(4), ABCID varchar(20), [AMT%] INT)
Sample Data (4700, 1, AMT%)
```

AMT% should equal AMT / SUM(AMT).  SUM(AMT) should only be summing the values where the MasterDept on Table 1 matches the MasterDept from the record on Table 2.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  MySQL, SQL Server 2008/20012 etc?

Comment: Sorry!!  I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: I am trying to Update Table 2 not insert into it as well

Comment: Are there multiple `AMT` values that would be combined? Or 1 per MasterDept and ABCID combination?

Comment: There is 1 AMT value per ABCID,  Multiple AMT values per MasterDept and multiple ABCID values per MasterDept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a window to get a partitioned `SUM()`:

```
SELECT MasterDept, ABCID, AMT, SUM(AMT) OVER(PARTITION BY MasterDept)
FROM #Table1
```

You can use that to get the percentage for each row to update your second table (this assumes 1 row per MasterDept/ABCID combination):

```
UPDATE A
SET A.[AMT%] = B.[AMT%]
FROM Table2 A
JOIN (SELECT MasterDept
           , ABCID
           , AMT
           , CASE WHEN SUM(AMT) OVER(PARTITION BY MasterDept) = 0 THEN 0
                  ELSE AMT*1.0/SUM(AMT) OVER(PARTITION BY MasterDept)
             END 'AMT%'
      FROM #Table1
      ) B 
    ON A.MasterDept = B.MasterDept
    AND A.ABCID = B.ABCID
```

As you can see in the subquery, a percent of total can be added to your Table1, so perhaps you don't even need Table2 as it's a bit redundant.

Update: You can use a `CASE` statement to handle a `SUM()` of 0.

Comment: When I run this script everything is just getting updated to 0.0000

Comment: You might have caught it between edits, I changed where the *1.0 portion was because I missed () when I first put it in.

Comment: Your exactly right!  I just made the change and it worked great! Thank you!

Comment: Consider clicking the checkmark to indicate that your question has been answered.

Comment: What would I need to add to your second code block to account for the situations where the sum = 0??  right now I am getting a divide by 0 error during the query.